# VSCode How run a task on quit or close folder?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I use vscode on my mac, the task i use to launch docker is working ok, now i want to, on close folder run shell commands to delete stop container, delete volumnes etc..
Can vscode task do that?
Thanks (sorry for my bad english, it isn't my first, or second language)

```
{
    // tasks.json
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Start Docker",
            "type": "shell",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen",
            },
            "osx":{
                "command":"open -a Docker"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently.
See [avaiable options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_run-behavior) and this [reported issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65986)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that if the task is left running indefinitely, you can emulate `folderClose` if the task handles the exit signal sent when you leave the folder or close VSCode. Here is an example with a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# autostart.sh

on_folder_close() {
    
    # This is run when the folder / VSCode closes
    # Use -v to remove volumes
    docker compose down -v
    
    trap - SIGINT
    kill -- -$$
}

trap on_folder_close SIGINT

# This is run when the folder is opened
# -d to run in detached mode
docker compose up -d

sleep infinity
```

This would be accompanied by a task that could look like this:

```json
{
    "label": "Start services",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "./autostart.sh",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
    },
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen",
    }
}
```

The disadvantage here is that the task will always be visible in the terminal view, but it helps if you set presentation.reveal to "silent".

While this produce the expected behavior, someone else should probably look it over, since I am not an expert on signal handling or bash.